# How to initialize AppDomain when hosting dotnet 6.0 via hostfxr?

Tags: .net-core, initialization, appdomain

I'm trying to implement custom dotnet host in C++ by using hostfxr:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting

It works, however System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain is not initialized correctly.
For example, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory is empty.

Is it possible to configure the default AppDomain by using only nethost.h and hostfxr.h headers or should I rather go deeper and try to touch coreclr.dll API?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

The following coreclr runtime property must be set:

```
hostfxr_set_runtime_property_value(ctx, L"APP_CONTEXT_BASE_DIRECTORY", L"path\\to\\application");
```

This way AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory is getting initialized.